# Whats Wikis questions and answers principles?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I am asking about the supposed principles that all the users need to follow on Stack Overflow,

There are some cases I want to understand:

1. Some one asked a question and made it as a wiki -> why all answers are wikis as well "I mean users used to make the answers as wikis, not forced to".
2. When its better to make a question as a wiki and when not?
3. When should you make an answer as a wiki and when not?
4. Whats the real purpose of Wikis on Stack Overflow, while I still see a lot of answers on the same wiki question?
5. Why wikis questions or answers votes, don't give to their owners more points? "I know its hard to calculate, but its also not fair to gain 100 votes on a question and not get at least one point, we need to think of a way"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Community Wiki is supposed to be a way to have a collection pot of information on some subject from the entire community.

So a CW does more things than you post. For example if you post an answer on a CW question and I edit this answer, your name will no longer appear. Since I am the last editor.

So any notion of ownership does not exist on a CW question.

Many users misunderstand CW's and many use them to ask subjective questions and prevent rep whoring on answers which many agree with. A CW question was not originally supposed to be about that.